# Django raw query filter by year and month

Tags: django, sqlite

I need to write django raw query for filtering year and month. for that I have tried following code.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT  SUM(work_time) AS sum FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id = %s AND tree_id=%s AND project_structure=%s AND year(date)=%s AND month(date)=%s  GROUP BY project_structure ', [employee_id,tree_id,project_structure,select_year,select_month] )
sum1=str(cursor.fetchone())
```

but it tells `no such function: year` what's wrong with my code?

Comment: year is your column name?

Comment: no column name is date

Comment: What database do you have as your backend?

Comment: sqlite database for now later i will change for mysql

Comment: @Lahiruzz then why did you tag mysql? And I don't think SQLite has `YEAR()` function.

Comment: @Bibhas : sorry for my mistake. how can I do with sqlite?

Comment: It doesn't have a `date()` type directly I would advice you to go for a MySQL solution now instead of later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite doesn't have a `YEAR()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). If you want year, you can use something like this -

```
select strftime('%Y', datetime(datefield, 'unixepoch')) as year from table_name
```

So instead of writing `year(date)=%s`, you could write `strftime('%Y', date) = %s`. It should work. I haven't tried it.

Or leave all these headache and use Django's ORM. You should be using that at the first place.

Edit:
According to OP, this query worked -

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(work_time) AS sum FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id = %s AND tree_id=%s AND project_structure=%s AND strftime('%%Y', date) = %s AND strftime('%%m', date) = %s GROUP BY project_structure ", employee_id, tree_id, project_structure, select_year, select_month])
```

The `%Y` needed to be escaped using `%%Y`.

Comment: i need to filter the year from table ? is there any function?

Comment: Now I  got :unsupported format character 'Y' (0x59) at index 140 I don't know why :(

Comment: Try `"%Y"` instead of `'%Y'`. Your terminals are single quoted.

Comment: same error. this is my query::   cursor.execute("SELECT  SUM(work_time) AS sum FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id = %s AND tree_id=%s AND project_structure=%s AND strftime('%y', date) = %s AND strftime('%m', date) = %s  GROUP BY project_structure ", [employee_id,tree_id,project_structure,select_year,select_month] )

Comment: Who said anything about `y`? It's `Y`. Read the doc please.

Comment: Finally I got correct one :  cursor.execute("SELECT  SUM(work_time) AS sum FROM structure_tracking_details WHERE employee_id = %s AND tree_id=%s AND project_structure=%s AND strftime('%%Y', date) = %s AND strftime('%%m', date) = %s  GROUP BY project_structure ", [employee_id,tree_id,project_structure,select_year,select_month] )       here %%Y and %%m. Thanks you very much @Bibhas for the help

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the ORM?

If you have a model like this:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    date_field = models.DateField()
    # your other fields
```

You can do this query using the [`year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) and [`month`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month) lookups:

```
Work.objects.filter(date_field__year=2013,date_field__month=2)
```

Now, to add the rest of your stuff, which is the summing of `work_time` and group by:

```
from django.models import Sum

Work.objects.filter(date_field__year=2013,
                    date_field__month=2,
                    employee_id=1,
                    ...).values('project_structure').aggregate(total=Sum('work_time'))
```

Comment: OP might just query some table that they haven't modeled.

Comment: @Burhan : Is there any function for Group by?

Comment: [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) @Lahiruzz

Comment: @Burhan:can you kindly help me to assign these sum value to some varible. var=total correct?

Comment: @Lahiruzz have a read through [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) of the manual; hopefully that will answer that question and any other.